# Vine API get userid

Tags: vine

Anybody knows how to get userid from username (https://vine.co/**ManUtd**) by using vine API? Search($username) returns so many users' info. That functions search by username, tags,..etc.

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

1. Enter in your browser address bar the URL
   https://api.vineapp.com/users/search/USERNAME_SEARCHING_FOR
2. Hit Enter.
3. You will get JSON code with `userId` key containing id of the user.

Credits : [This](http://stack.looks-awesome.com/docs/Setup/Find_Vine_ID) page.